# Flutter Firebase Auth new update

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i have a working app with an "old" firebase auth widget.
Now the auth was updated and nothing is working anymore.

can you help me fixing it????

This is the whole widget:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged => _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(
        (User user) => user?.uid,
      );

  //Email & Password Sign up
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password, String name) async {
    final currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email,
      password: password,
    );

    //Update the Username
    var userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
    userUpdateInfo.displayName = name;
    await currentUser.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
    await currentUser.reload();
    return currentUser.uid;
  }

//Email Password Sign In
  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password))
        .user
        .uid;
  }

//Sign Out
  signOut() {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

And this part from widget is not working anymore:

```
    //Update the Username
    var userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
    userUpdateInfo.displayName = name;
    await currentUser.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
    await currentUser.reload();
    return currentUser.uid;
```

Here are the Errors:

error: The method 'UserUpdateInfo' isn't defined for the type 'AuthService'.
error: The method 'updateProfile' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'.
error: The method 'reload' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'.
error: The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration) for FlutterFire, and at the updated [reference documentation the `firebase_auth` library](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/).

For example, the [`updateProfile` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updateProfile.html) and [`reload` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/reload.html) and the [`uid` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/uid.html) are now defined on the `User` object.

The same `User` object also has an [`updateProfile` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updateProfile.html), which takes the `displayName` as an optional, named parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You should decrease the version of library or refactor your code by new documention of this library.